# Congratulations, and thanks, to Daniel Ballinger for reaching 100,000 reputation!

Tags: discussion

100,000 is such a nice, round number<sup>in base 10, at least</sup>.

Let's take this opportunity to celebrate [**Daniel Ballinger**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger) for more than a decade of contributions here on SFSE, for his [impact and expertise](https://www.fishofprey.com/) throughout the ecosystem, and for his sterling work as a product manager on the Apex team.

Daniel, we are grateful for everything you do!

Comment: Great knowledge sharing with excellent reach. Congrats on this milestone.

Comment: you next @David :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks David,

It's certainly been an adventure from when I started contributing to the SFSE in 2012, through to being an MVP, and then onto the Product Manager for Apex itself within Salesforce.

I've appreciated the StackExchange community throughout it all. Such a breadth of knowledge and helpfulness that I'm thankful for the opportunity to contribute to.

Comment: COngratulations Daniel.

Comment: Congratulations @Daniel Ballinger !!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to you @Daniel. Thanks for all your contributions..